# Complement of the support of measure on R^n has measure 0

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

How do we prove that $\mu (B) = 0$ for any ball $B$ such that $B \subset S^c$?

For any $x \in S^c$, there exists $r_x > 0$ such that $\mu \left( B(x, r_x) \right) = 0$.

Why there exists a countable cover for $S^c$ such that

$$
S^c = \cup_{i = 1}^{\infty} B(p_i, r_{p_i}) 
\text{ and }
\mu \left( B(p_i, r_{p_i}) \right) = 0 \text{ for any } i \ge 1
$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(p_i,r_i)_i$ to be an enumeration of $A = \{r,q \in \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q^n : \mu(B(p,r))=0\}$.

Then, if $x \in S^c$, then there is $r>0$ such that $\mu(B(x,r)) = 0$. Now we just need to find $p,r'\in \mathbb Q^n  \times \mathbb Q$ such that $$x\in B(p,r') \subset B(x,r).$$

This is easy, by density of rationals, and a standard drawing of a picture of a ball inside another ball.

Comment: is $\mu\left(B_n\right) = 0$ necessarily true for any collection of open balls $B_n,\,n=1,2,\ldots$ where $\cup_n B_n = S^c$?

Comment: ^^^ I suppose this is obviously true in light of this answer. I am curious if my above comment can be shown without use of the $A$ construction above, i.e. without first explicitly constructing an enumerable collection of open balls with measure zero.